# Power old mobile phone with a 9V battery

Tags: power-supply, cellphone

I have an old Nokia N73 which i cannot charge since the battery input is broken. I'd like to power it directly through a 9V battery. On the old original battery it says it outputs 3.7V. However i cannot find any information on how much current (amps) should be provided to the phone. Therefore i'm not able to calculate what kind of resistor should i use in order to prevent the phone from damage by connecting it to a 9V battery. 
I'm a beginner in electronics and I would be gratefull for any advice on that topic.

Comment: Do you have the voltage rating of old charger?

Comment: It's a standard old nokia charger which outputs DC 5V / 1200mA. However i'm trying to power the phone without using an old battery / charger. I'm trying to connect directly to pins inside the phone.

Comment: Just power it from a LIPO battery like the original. 9V are terrible batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a resistor to drop the voltage from the 9v battery to a device like a cell phone that is going to have a varying load at 3.7v, which will range from tens or hundreds of microamps when the phone is idle and the screen is dark, to short bursts over an amp when the phone is connecting to a cell tower.  Using a resistor as a voltage regulator is generally a very bad idea anyway.

9v batteries don't have much current capacity. You might be able to get by using using 3xAA cells feeding into a voltage regulator to drop the voltage to 3.7v.  A typical 9v battery has a 625 mAh capacity, an AA cell over four times as much (2850 mAh).

Unfortunately, you can't really use a ordinary diode (like the 1N4001, with a 0.7v forward voltage) to create a voltage drop either, because AA cells drop fairly rapidly from an initial voltage of a little above 1.5v down to 1.2v or so, and by then you're out of gas (you probably need a minimum of 3v before the phone shuts down).

Since cell phones are designed to work with a full charged Li-Poly (or similar) battery of 4.2v, you might get by using three AA cells and a [Schotkky diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode) with a minimum forward voltage Vf of 0.4v so the voltage doesn't go above 4.2v. But this will still only make use of about 2/3 of your battery capacity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks tcrosley. I forgot to add that i'm not looking for a long term solution, i just need to boot the phone for 10-15 minutes to dump some old photos. So i guess even 625mAh from a 9V battery should be fine. I will follow your recommendation and try with voltage regulator. And sorry for a noob question but: 1. Why is a voltage regulator better than a resistor ? 2. How many amps should / will be produced by a voltage regulator ?

Comment: If you only need this to work for 10-15 minutes, use three new AA cells and a 1N4001 diode (which you can get from Radio Shack when you buy the batteries).  The problem with the resistor is, as I mentioned in my initial paragraph, the phone will not be drawing a constant current, and the varying current will create a varying voltage drop due to [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) V=IR.